# JS Date.UTC() timezone

Tags: javascript, utc

Simple question, javascript has getUTCHours(), getUTCMinutes() and so on, is this basically a universal time that every computer in the world will get the exact same UTC minutes, hours, seconds? regardless of whatever time is set on user's computer.
For instance 100 computers around the world have a js file that says in getUTCHours 18, say Happy Holiday, will everybody do it at this exact same hour?

It's quite a simple question, please redirect me to where I can ask this if it's not related to programming.

Comment: UTC: "Universal Time Coordinated", and yes at any given instant on Earth, every spot on the planet has the same UTC time, ignoring clocks being wrong (which of course is also a universal reality).

Comment: "UTC" = "Coordinated Universal Time" = time without a timezone, or more specifically +- 0 hours.

Comment: Assuming those computers' times are correct, yes.

Comment: If that "Happy Holiday" message appears at 04:00 local time, there won't be many people noticing it there. Not everyone keeps their computer on at night.

Comment: @trincot I keep my computer on 24/7. I just don't look at it at 4 in the morning, so I still won't really see the message.

Comment: Thanks! 
@ceejayoz, how do you mean if times are correct?

Comment: @emilien If it's 4:30pm, and you set your computer to 4:35pm, your computer's UTC times will also be off by 5 minutes. Most computers these days get regularly updated times from a timeserver (NTP), but it's not guaranteed.